# Connecting AzureAppService .Net Backend to SQL Database

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, connection-string, azure-mobile-services

I am following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk)

I've successfully created and modified the project to my needs.
Now when it comes to Seeding my Database I would like to Seed and Debug with the "Prod" Database (I know thats not best practice but still .. :D ).

The problem is that in the project you get created from `Azure` this is the `Connectionstring`:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-[MyAppName]-20161222051819.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-[MyAppName]-20161222051819;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Now when I want to  `Debug` controllers and stuff in my backend. Can I do this on the actual BackendDB in Azure ?

Or is this `.mdf` created and stored in Azure when I publish the `API` to Azure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The connection string is set within the Azure Portal (use Data Connections menu option within your app service)
2. You should be using EF Code-First Migrations if you are working with ASP.NET SDK
3. You can attach the debugger to your running Azure instance within Visual Studio - go to Server Explorer, log into Azure, expand App Services, right-click on your service and select "Attach Debugger"  (Make sure you deploy a debug version of the service, not a release version)

For more information, see my book at http://aka.ms/zumobook